# Same TD height for two tables displayed side by side

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created two table that are displaying side by side. In each table there are  header sections and under each section there is data. The problem i am running into is aligning the header of each section side by side as some of the sections have less data than the other. Below is what I have tried so far with CSS and html but its not working. Hoping that someone can assist.

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: uncollapse;
}

#customers th {
  broder: none;
}

#customers td {
  broder: none;
  min-height: 33%;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: Center;
  background-color: Gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers" style="display: inline-block; border: 15px solid;   float: left; ">
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 1?</td>
    <td align="center" font='red'>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question2?</td>
    <td align="center">N/A</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question3</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th></th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 1?</td>
    <td align="center">USD</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Question 2?</td>
    <td align="center">USD</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 3?</td>
    <td align="center">USD</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 3?</td>
    <td align="center">N/A</td>


  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th></th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Question 2
    </td>
    <td>See Link
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Direct Debit</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th></th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>


    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 5</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td> </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td> </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>header 6</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question?</td>
    <td align="center">N/A</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>HEader 7</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question
    </td>
    <td align="center">See Link
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>

</table>
</div>


<table id="customers" style="display: inline-block; border: 15px solid; float: left; ">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question1</td>
    <td> </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td> </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>header 2</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question?</td>
    <td align="center">N/A</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>HEader 3</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question
    </td>
    <td align="center">See Link
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>


  <tr>
    <th>Header 4</th>
    <th></th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td>
      <td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Question</td>

    <td></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <th>HEader 5</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question?</td>
    <td align="center">IAS</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <th>Header 6</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td align="center">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <th>header 7</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question</td>
  </tr>





</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried a fixed header height or using js to match them after the page is loaded?

Comment: can you please me some example. I have tried the fixed header height but it didnt work. I had it in my css, i was actually researching and my this eq_row_height thing what is this and how can I use it because when I just added the code it didnt change anything

Comment: Sure - I'm thinking we will actually use js to add empty rows to the table and set a minimum row height. Is the empty row under heading 3 in the first table just a typo in the sample data?

Comment: Hi, no actually thats how it will be because some of questions will not be actually questions just a statement. So the answer section will be blank and I also want to display these tables in the center they are align left I tried to add the code to center them but it wont move.

Comment: Okay,  so we can set a min height and then every row can be the same height, even empty ones. I think you will have more maintainable code if we break the tables into a table of tables. This will allow for long data that wraps onto a second row and no js. If that seems like it might be okay, I can code up a snippet but let me know if that is not an option.

Comment: Yes please I would like that. Thank you for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of the top three sections of your code with a table wrapped around the inner tables for structure. Setting `vertical-align: top` on the td's of the container table keeps the inner tables at the same vertical position even when one is taller than the next.

```css
.even-heights {
  font-size: 0;
  background: black;
  border: 7.5px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.even-heights td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.customers {
  margin: 7.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: uncollapse;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customers th {
  border: none;
}

.customers td {
  border: none;
  /* tr must have a height then... min-height: 33%; */
  min-height: 18px;
  min-width: 62px;
}

.customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.customers tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.customers th {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: Center;
  background-color: Gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="even-heights">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>Heading 1</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question 1?</td>
          <td align="center" font='red'>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question2?</td>
          <td align="center">N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question3</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question1</td>
          <td> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question</td>
          <td> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>Heading 2</th>
          <th></th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Question 1?</td>
          <td align="center">USD</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Question 2?</td>
          <td align="center">USD</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Question 3?</td>
          <td align="center">USD</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question 3?</td>
          <td align="center">N/A</td>


        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>header 2</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question</td>
          <td align="center">Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question?</td>
          <td align="center">N/A</td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>Heading 3</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question 1</td>
          <td align="center">Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question 2
          </td>
          <td>See Link
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Direct Debit</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>HEader 3</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question
          </td>
          <td align="center">See Link
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Question
          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```